# read in semi colon separated CSV files

Tags: matlab, csv

I have a CSV file which I want to read in using matlab.

I've tried using `csvread` but it does not seem to recognize the semi-colon as the delimiter. Is there any other way?

```
R;W    
100;0.1    
200;0.5    
300;0.9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html) instead and specify the [delimeter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html#inputarg_delimiter) to be a semi-colon. You will also want to set the row offset to 1 so you skip the first non-numeric row.

```
data = dlmread('filename.csv', ';', 1);
```

Comment: That works just fine, thank you so much for your help.